# PyQt: Widget constantly moving to position (0, 0)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have made a PyQt app with event filter that makes a widget follow mouse movement, It follows the mouse movement and sometimes goes back to position `0, 0`...

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import resources



class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget(self) # Central Widget
        self.edit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self) # Field that show's mouse position
        self.somewidget = QtGui.QPushButton(self) # Widget that will follow mouse    movement
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        self.edit.move(0, 0)
        self.somewidget.show()
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self) # Timer that will be used to set a little interval for mouse movement, to make it smoother.
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.movefunc)



    def eventFilter(self, source, event): # Defining event type to follow mouse movement without button.
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:
            if event.buttons() == QtCore.Qt.NoButton:
                self.pos = event.pos()  # Define full position.
                self.edit.setText('x: %d, y: %d' % (self.pos.x(), self.pos.y())) # show's mouse x and y position in field.
                self.timer.start(5) # starts timer for 5 milliseconds.
            else:
                pass
        return QtGui.QMainWindow.eventFilter(self, source, event)

    def movefunc(self):
        self.somewidget.move(self.pos.x(), self.pos.y()) # moves widget to mouse position in every 5 milliseconds.




if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    app.installEventFilter(win)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

so as you can see widget moves every 5 milliseconds, so it can be more smoother, but it does get back to position `0, 0` sometimes (every 1-2 second), what may the problem be? How can i limit it to certain positions, with it being smooth?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Why would the button move when the mouse moves?

Answer (score 0):

A few things

You shouldn't have to call `timer.start()` more than once.  Once the timer begins, it's going to continue triggering every 5 milliseconds until you call `timer.stop()`.

The coordinate system for the `Window` and the button aren't the same.  Coordinates are always in the geometry of their parent.  For the `Window`, that means global coordinates, because it's a top level window.  For the button, the coordinates are in the geometry of the window, because the window is its parent.  So giving the button coordinates from the window doesn't really make much sense.

Comment: I am trying to make a scope thing for my game, so background moves in scope, with mouse movement, how can i achieve that differently?